# Test session created by hub but not executed by selenium node

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, kubernetes, selenium-grid

I'm using the latest selenium and firefox versions(webdriver 55.0.3). On the Selenium Grid console the capabilities of my firefox node(s) are: 
`[{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=55.0.3, platform=LINUX}]`

Currently when my tests script is running, what happens is that the script stalls on trying to start the remote webdriver and then times out marking the Web UI tests as "completed". The script then moves on to other non UI tests. At the end of the test execution, it will show that all the non-UI tests have passed but it doesn't say that the UI ones have failed or have been skipped. Their status is unknown. The message at the end would be something like

```
Tests Passed: 80
Skipped: 0
Failed: 0
```

When in reality there should be 100 tests in total including the UI tests. Below is part of the logs from the hub after the test execution is complete:

```
20:04:28.043 INFO - my-browser-pod1 [bash, -c, cleanup-container.sh]
20:04:28.173 INFO - my-browser-pod1
20:04:28.174 DEBUG - Test count: 14
20:04:28.174 DEBUG - Test count with video: 1
20:05:27.854 INFO - Mismatched capabilities. Creating a synthetic w3c capability.
20:05:27.856 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@7865a886, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAK2gO0sAAAAAAAAAA..., unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}]
20:05:27.856 DEBUG - Validating {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore} in node with capabilities {browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.857 DEBUG - Validating {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore} in node with capabilities {browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.857 DEBUG - Validating {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore} in node with capabilities {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=61.0.3163.100, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.858 DEBUG - Validating {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore} in node with capabilities {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=55.0.3, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.858 DEBUG - Validating {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore} in node with capabilities {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=61.0.3163.100, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.858 DEBUG - Validating {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore} in node with capabilities {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=61.0.3163.100, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.859 DEBUG - Validating {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore} in node with capabilities {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=55.0.3, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.859 DEBUG - Validating {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore} in node with capabilities {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=55.0.3, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.859 DEBUG - Validating {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore} in node with capabilities {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=55.0.3, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.859 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, acceptSslCerts=true, screen-resolution=1900x1880, tz=Greenwich, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, screenResolution=1900x1880, resolution=1900x1880, version=55.0.3, platform=LINUX}
20:05:27.859 DEBUG - http://172.17.0.5:40005 Creating session for: {loggingPrefs={browser=SEVERE}, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, timeZone=Greenwich, version=55.0.3, platform=ANY, public=share, acceptSslCerts=true, acceptInsecureCerts=true, name=dockerdev : Web UI Smoke test, browserName=firefox, idle-timeout=90, platformName=ANY, maxDuration=1800, firefox_profile=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, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore}
20:05:27.859 DEBUG - http://172.17.0.5:40005 lastCommand: POST - /session executing...
20:05:28.029 INFO - http://172.17.0.5:40005 AFTER_SESSION command received. Cleaning up node for reuse, used 2 of max 4
20:05:28.029 INFO - http://172.17.0.5:40005 stop-video: Video recording is disabled
20:05:28.030 INFO - my-selenium-pod2 [bash, -c, transfer-logs.sh]
20:05:28.031 DEBUG - http://172.17.0.5:40005 lastCommand: POST - /session executed.
20:05:28.031 INFO - http://172.17.0.5:40005 start-video: Video recording is disabled
20:05:28.149 INFO - my-selenium-pod2 
20:05:28.281 WARN - http://172.17.0.5:40005 Error while copying the logs
java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:307)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)
    at java.io.InputStream.skip(InputStream.java:224)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.skip(IOUtils.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.consumeRemainderOfLastBlock(TarArchiveInputStream.java:668)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.getRecord(TarArchiveInputStream.java:388)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.getNextTarEntry(TarArchiveInputStream.java:265)
    at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.proxy.DockerSeleniumRemoteProxy.copyLogs(DockerSeleniumRemoteProxy.java:445)
    at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.proxy.DockerSeleniumRemoteProxy.processContainerAction(DockerSeleniumRemoteProxy.java:399)
    at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.proxy.DockerSeleniumRemoteProxy.cleanupNode(DockerSeleniumRemoteProxy.java:468)
    at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.proxy.DockerSeleniumRemoteProxy.afterSession(DockerSeleniumRemoteProxy.java:262)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.TestSlot.performAfterSessionEvent(TestSlot.java:247)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry._release(Registry.java:129)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry.access$100(Registry.java:45)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry$1.run(Registry.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20:05:28.284 INFO - my-selenium-pod2 [bash, -c, cleanup-container.sh]
20:05:28.418 INFO - my-selenium-pod2 
20:05:28.429 DEBUG - Test count: 15
20:05:28.429 DEBUG - Test count with video: 1
```

The `Error while copying the logs` message can be ignored as it is unrelated/expected. To me it seems like the issue is related to invalid capabilities, but I can't seem to find and major differences between the requested capabilities and the capabilities of the configured firefox pods aside from the platform field. My tests also include some other fields in the request like the `acceptInsecureCerts=true` field but I don't feel like it has any impact on the testing. The way I trace the logs above is that the hub gets a request with the test capabilities, finds a matching node then creates a test session for that capability. But after that the whole test isn't run and it goes straight to the end of the test. I can only see the `lastCommand` and `AFTER_SESSION` commands. Any ideas on why it would be doing this or how I should approach this issue? Thanks!